# Apple Script: select files on desktop

Tags: applescript

I want to select some files (for example, "test.txt") on the desktop using Apple Script.

I do that:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 103
```

(simulation press key "F11") to show desktop.

And after that I would like to select my file "test.txt" and see this selection on the desktop. This code:

```
tell application "Finder" to select file "test.txt" of folder "Desktop" of home
```

select my file in "Finder". This is not what I want to.

I want to see the selection of my files on the desktop (not in the window of Finder, that show folder 'Dektop')

Comment: "This is not what I want to." What do you want to do instead or why is this not what you want?

Comment: I want to see the selection of my files on the desktop (not in the window of Finder, that show folder 'Dektop')

Comment: ohh i see you want to select the files in the desktop vie not in a finder window ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the selection property instead of using the select command:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selection to item 1 of desktop
end tell
```

This would also keep existing selections:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    select window of desktop
    if selection is {} then set selection to item 1 of desktop
end tell
```